# Is there a way to show mouse clicks on screen?

Tags: shadowplay, nvidia-geforce-experience

I'm recording to make a showcase of weapons and comparisons between each game of a saga, and I expect the viewer to understand the behaviour of each weapon whenever I'm [holding a certain amount of time / pressing]:

- Left button
- Right button
- Middle button
- Combining left and right button in this order
- Viceversa

Is there a way to do this with shadowplay? I believe with OBS there may be a way, but I'd like to emphasize the use of Shadowplay since OBS sometimes fails.

Comment: Not super relevant, but somewhat anecdotal; I find OBS way more straightforward than Shadowplay when I tried them both.

Comment: What makes you think so?

Comment: (I'm just curious :o)

Comment: I couldn't get Shadowplay to connect to twitch.  The options were very limited and didn't give much help.  OBS you can play around with basically everything; and it pretty much always worked for me, any tweaking was just for preference.